# VersionControlServer.GetChangesetProperty available filter

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

The [VersionControlServer.GetChangesetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ff733080(v%3Dvs.100)) allows a `filter` as the parameter, which - I think - allows me to specify the property I'm trying to get.
However, I can't find a list with the available strings.

My goal is to get the `CheckinNote` property of the changeset. Using `.GetChangesetProperty(changeSetId, "CheckinNote")` returs null.

Does someone have an idea or a list with the available filter?

---

**Update**

It looks like it that method is referring to the `Changeset.Properties` property, I'll see if I can get any more information on this.

Comment: Hi Trexx, any update on this, have you figured out it. Did you get the info you need from Changeset.Properties  property?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Thanks for your comment but I managed to get it working using a different approach.